# What is the best practice to redirect a shorten domain to the specific React path?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, dns

I have created an React web application, and the user path is something like https://abcde.com/user/:username

Also I have purchased a short URL for this application (no webhost).I want to redirect this domain, for example, from https://a.com/:username to https://abcde/user/:username What is the best way to redirect this shorten URL to my React App?

Comment: What do you exactly want to understand? The question is not clear.

Comment: for example: https://youtu.be/ is redirecting to https://youtube.com/?feature=youtu.be

I want my website is redirecting from https://myshortlink/user to https://myLongLink.com/p/user